# Using embedded ActiveMQ Artemis in Spring Boot 3 with OpenWire protocol

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to use an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis broker in my Spring Boot 3 application and activate the OpenWire protocol.

This should be possible with an acceptor like `tcp://0.0.0.0:616161?protocols=CORE,OPENWIRE` as it says [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/protocols-interoperability.html#configuring-acceptors).

I added these to dependencies to use the ActiveMQ Artemis broker.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-jakarta-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and use this BOM from Spring Boot

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But when I start the Application this is logged:

```
AMQ222203: Classpath lacks a protocol-manager for protocol OPENWIRE, Protocol being ignored on acceptor TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyAcceptorFactory) ?scheme=tcp&port=61616&host=0-0-0-0&protocols=CORE,AMQP,OPENWIRE
```

To enable the `amqp` I added the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-amqp-protocol</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I do the same with the OpenWire (also Spring does not provide a version for this dependecy):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-openwire-protocol</artifactId>
    <version>2.31.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The server start crashes with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

I downloaded the ActiveMQ Artemis bundle and started the server with the same configuration there and it is starting with OpenWire support. I looked into the `lib` folder of the bundled server and there is also a `artemis-openwire-protocol` jar is included.

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>artemis-protocols</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <version>2.31.2</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>artemis-openwire-protocol</artifactId>
```

The standalone ActiveMQ Artemis broker is able to accept OpenWire clients. What do have I to do to enable it with the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis broker? Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

In short, there currently is no way to support OpenWire clients of any kind using the ActiveMQ Artemis Jakarta broker. I've opened [ARTEMIS-4567](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4567) to support this.

The problem is that the `artemis-openwire-protocol` dependency you're using depends on `org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.18.3` which contains the actual OpenWire protocol implementation as well as the OpenWire JMS client implementation. This dependency uses and implements classes in the `javax` namespace which are incompatible with Spring Boot 3.x (which uses the `jakarta` namespace). Because of this code in `artemis-openwire-protocol` itself also references classes in `javax`.

Lastly, it's worth noting that existing OpenWire JMS clients using the `javax` namespace may break when using a broker with OpenWire + Jakarta.

If you really need to use JMS applications that use the `javax` namespace then I recommend you replace the OpenWire JMS client jars in those applications with the core JMS client jars from ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client`). If your JMS applications are written properly (i.e. they don't use any implementation objects) then it should be a straight-forward switch. Just replace the jars and the update your `jndi.properties` files. The core JMS client uses the core protocol which isn't tightly coupled with JMS so you can mix and match clients & brokers using both namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem ist, that I want to provide the openwire protocol with the embedded broker. I can not change the clients of the broker. We want to update your broker application to spring boot 3 and there the Broker implementation changed from ActiveMQ to Artemis. The clients of our application should not notice this change (expect some required URL changes). As the standalone Artemis is able to provide the Openwire protocol without any further setup I guess the problem is the dependecies used my the spring boot starter. But I can not figure out, what I have to change.

Comment: There is nothing that you can change due to the fact that there is no OpenWire protocol implementation for ActiveMQ Artemis that supports Jakarta.